# Is guaranteed that class members are disposed at the time that the class is disposed

Tags: c++, destructor, composition

I have the following situation:

I have class A that contains a stack member object from class B:

```
Class A{
    B b;
}
```

I am using B object to redefine the behavior of the initialization and destruction of A.

```
Class B{
    B(){cout<<"taken care of some specific context initialization"<<endl;}
    ~B(){cout<<"cleaning the context initialization done before"<<endl;}
}
```

This is working so far because ~B() is being called when b is destroyed (I guess it is done after A destructor).

This is the behavior I am looking for, but I am scared about the possibility of the compiler saying: "Hey, you are not using the object, I am going to reclaim the memory before". I guess it should to happen, but is it possible in any compiler? I mean, is it set on the standard that you have to wait for A to be destroyed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `b` is not destroyed ` "after A". It is destroyed during `A`'s destruction process. The compiler cannot decide to destroy it before or after.

Comment: The compiler can't do that because the destructor has side-effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ follows an as-if behavior, meaning it is *theoretically* possible for `b` to be destroyed before **as long as the behavior of the program isn't affected**. And if it isn't affected, it doesn't really matter when it is destroyed.

In practice though, `b` will be destroyed right after the destructor of its owner `A` instance will be destroyed.

It is guaranteed by:

#### 12.4 Destructors [class.dtor]

> 8) **After executing the body of the destructor** and destroying any
>   automatic objects allocated within the body, **a destructor for class X
>   calls the destructors for X’s direct non-variant non-static data
>   members, the destructors for X’s direct base classes** and, if X is the
>   type of the most derived class (12.6.2), its destructor calls the
>   destructors for X’s virtual base classes. [...] (emphasis mine)

Note that an implementation whose observable behavior acts as-if this was happening is still standard-compliant. In your particular case, since the destructor has IO operations, it's guaranteed that this behavior actually takes place.